# Reverse TreeMap Key and Values Testing

Tags: java, treemap

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
public class Map {
    public TreeMap<Integer, String> reverseBook = new TreeMap <Integer, String>();
    public void reverse(TreeMap<String, Integer> phoneBook) {
        for (String key: phoneBook.keySet()) {
            reverseBook.put(phoneBook.get(key), key);
            return reverseBook;
        }
    }
```

I am a beginner coder and I am having trouble on how to test this map using main method testing. I think I wrote the method correctly but I am stumped on how to test it.

Comment: You are trying to return a `Map` inside a `void` method, are you sure it is compiling?

Answer (score 1):

A first test should always check if the method works as expected for sensible arguments. So, prepare an input phonebook, an expected output book, and check if the result of running your method produces a book that is the same as your expected output book. E.g. like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<String, Integer> input = new TreeMap<>();
    input.put("a", 1);
    input.put("b", 2);

    TreeMap<Integer, String> expectedOutput = new TreeMap<>();
    expectedOutput.put(1, "a");
    expectedOutput.put(2, "b");

    reverse(input);

    System.out.println("Works ok: " + reverseBook.equals(expectedOutput));
}

public static TreeMap<Integer, String> reverseBook = new TreeMap <Integer, String>();
public static void reverse(TreeMap<String, Integer> phoneBook) {
    for (String key: phoneBook.keySet()) {
        reverseBook.put(phoneBook.get(key), key);
    }
}
```

Do take a look at testing frameworks like JUnit which simplify this kind of thing - the main method here is just to get you up and running.

Further down the line check how the method behaves for weird conditions - an empty book, when the book is null etc.

Also, before posting code here, please make sure it compiles first.

Comment: Thank you and noted! I apologize for not checking before!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your method return a TreeMap instead of void

```
public TreeMap<String, Integer> reverse(TreeMap<String, Integer> phoneBook) {
    for (String key: phoneBook.keySet()) {
        reverseBook.put(phoneBook.get(key), key);
        return reverseBook;
    }
```

And then you can test it like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
...
TreeMap<String, Integer> test = reverse( your_original_treemap );

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

Comment: @MaryJ Welcome , a vote or a mark can be appreciated if it helped you